# -bash: php: command not found - Centos6.7

Tags: centos, yum

I have two versions of PHP installed on the server:

```
$ find / -name php -type f
```

result:

```
/opt/rh/php54/root/usr/bin/php
/opt/rh/php55/root/usr/bin/php
```

I've added php54 path to `~/.bash_profile`

```
$ echo $PATH
```

result:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin:/root/bin:/opt/rh/php54/root/usr/bin/php
```

however `$ php -v` still doesn't work.

in fact if I `$ cd /opt/rh/php54/root/usr/bin` and run `php -v` from the directory itself, it still doesn't work. I get:

```
-bash: php: command not found
```

PHP is installed as there are websites running, just command line is not working...

Both

```
php55-php-cli-5.5.21-4.el6.x86_64
php54-php-cli-5.4.40-2.el6.x86_64
```

are installed...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrong path:

find results:

```
/opt/rh/php54/root/usr/bin/php
                           ^^^--- your php binary
```

$PATH expects only **DIRECTORIES**. You listed the above path in $PATH, which means that the shell will be searching for `.../usr/bin/php/php`. Note the doubled `php`. First one is the "directory" that you added in $PATH, while the second one is the program you're trying to run. The $PATH entry should be JUST `.../usr/bin/`, WITHOUT the `php`.

Comment: Still relevant, thank you very much!