# Linux Bash: Run php script located in different folder

Tags: php, linux, bash, shell, command-line-interface

What I attempt: `php folder/file` 
I get `command not found`

The PHP location is `/usr/local/bin/php-7.0`

Comment: What returns `whereis php` ?

Comment: `/usr/local/bin/php-7.0 folder/file`. To avoid `command not found` later, add `/usr/local/bin` to your `$PATH` variable.

Comment: @Syscall it returns pretty much nothing `php [user@example.com curerentfolder]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [-bash: php: command not found - Centos6.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37994827/bash-php-command-not-found-centos6-7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The executable seems to be named `php-7.0`:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/php-7.0 /path/to/file.php
```

Instead of call the fully qualified path, you could make sure that `/usr/local/bin` is in your $PATH, e.g.:

```
$ export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/bin
```

and then call `php-7.0`:

```
$ php-7.0 /path/to/file.php
```

Comment: And maybe a `ln -s` to link `php` to `php-7.0`?

Comment: @Syscall or even `alias`, or better yet, use `alternatives`.